# Runtime Error - web.config

Tags: python, flask, web-config

I have created a website using flask that takes in a string, creates a url based off the string, parses the url and then feeds it back into the website.  I created a function to do so and it works perfectly. However when I implement it within my flask program it started throwing a runtime error that states:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
Details:To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a customErrors tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This customErrors tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I am not familiar with creating a web.config or how to implement this within my flask program.  Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

Function that works when ran on it's own:

```
def parse_wotc():
    set_list = []
    # Manually enter in value for test
    card_url = 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=' + 
                'mountain' # (replace mountain) card_name.replace(' ', '+')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(card_url).text, 'html.parser')

    for image in soup.find_all('img'):
        if image.get('title') is not None:
            set_list.append(image.get('title'))
    print(set_list)
    return set_list
```

webapp code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    card_name = None
    card_url = '/static/images/card_back.jpg'

    if request.form.get('random_button'):
        card_url, card_name = random_card_image(list_card_names)
        # When function ran here it give the error
        parse_wotc(card_name)

def random_card_image(list_card_names):
    """This function will pull a random card name from the provided list and 
    return to main program"""
    card_name = random.choice(list_card_names)
    card_url = 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?name=' + 
                card_name.replace(' ', '+').lower() + \
                '&type=card'
    return card_url, card_name
```

Comment: if you need help, you need to show us the code!

Comment: @Daniel - Here you go sir (edited post).  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I understand that you are not developing this app locally?

Comment: As of right now it is being ran locally on 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: ok, so I am still troubleshooting, but it would seem that the problem is with how the random_card_image() is sending the data to the parse_wotc().  I added a text field to the app so that I can manually enter in names and it works perfectly every time through the site.

Comment: if you want a full go at it: https://github.com/pyRN/That_Card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a couple of hours to determine what the issue was, but it is working now.  The issue is that I made a text file that had a list of card names that I was pulling from to create a random selection - the text file however included a trailing \n on each entry.  Therefore it was creating a url with \n in it which was unnoticeable at the time and causing an error.  I used rsplit() when creating the name list to remove the trailing \n and now it works perfectly.

Comment: the silliest mistakes are the ones which take longer to find. glad you solved it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look regardless.